# Azure B2C custom policy read value from query param and pass to REST API body

Tags: rest, azure-ad-b2c, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have query param 'invite_token'. I want to read this from Signup page and send this to REST API post body.

```
  <ClaimType Id="inviteToken">
    <DataType>string</DataType>
  </ClaimType>
```

REST API Technical Profile,

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SIGNUP-VALIDATION">
          <DisplayName>Validate user input data</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
            Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://mydomain/verify-email</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="firstName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="lastName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="inviteToken" PartnerClaimType="inviteToken" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

My customised LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail is,

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
  <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
    Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"
      DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:register_email}"
      AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="inviteToken"
      DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:invite_token}"
      AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <DisplayClaims>
    <!-- <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" /> -->
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />

    <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="inviteToken" />
  </DisplayClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

    <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="inviteToken" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-API-SIGNUP-VALIDATION" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I am expecting my request body will be email, firstName, lastName and inviteToken.
I am receiving email, firstName and lastName but not inviteToken. How do I sent the inviteToken in my request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have it processed inside of your `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail` unless you **want** to show it to the user.

You can simply pass it in to the `REST-API-SIGNUP-VALIDATION` technical profile, as shown below.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SIGNUP-VALIDATION">
    <DisplayName>Validate user input data</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
    Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://mydomain/verify-email</Item>
      <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
      <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
      <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="firstName" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="lastName" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="inviteToken" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:invite_token}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Another common practice is the first Orchestration step in your policy's user journey is to parse the input parameters you require. An example of this is:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="InitialiseJourney" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="InitialiseJourney"/>
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="InitialiseJourney">
  <DisplayName>Initialise journey claims</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.UserJourneyContextProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <OutputClaims>
    <!-- Invitation Claims -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:register_email}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="inviteToken" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:invite_token}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: If you want to display it to the user, let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I want this inviteToken in the the jwt Token. I tried add it via OutputClaim. But Its not there in the jwt payload.

Comment: In your `<RelyingParty>` technical profile you can add it as an output claim such as `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="inviteToken" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:invite_token}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />` - This is the easiest advice I have as the other edits depend on the implementation. You should consider if the relying party needs the invite id, at the point of redemption it should be marked as claimed and invalidated in the b2c flow.